# Bubble sorting doesnt work from the first time in the linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to do bubble sorting for my linked list, it doesn't work from the first time, but if I call the function twice it sorts well, for example if the list is: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1, The sorting returns 4 3 2 1 5 6 7 8 9! What's the mistake here?

```
void sort() {

if(Head == NULL)
    cout << "Sorry but your list is empty! \n";
else {

    int i,j,temp,k = count();
    node *current,*nextNode;

    for(i=0; i<k-1; i++,k--) {
        current = Head;
        nextNode = current->Next;

        for(j = 1; j<k; j++) {
            if(current->item > nextNode->item){
                temp = current->item;
                current->item = nextNode->item;
                nextNode->item = temp;
            }
            current = current->Next;
            nextNode = nextNode->Next;
        }
    }
    cout << "Sorting Succeeded!\n";
}
}
```

Comment: I take it from the swap code this isn't about swapping nodes in the linked list, but rather their contained values. I only bring it up because most data structures and algorithm courses don't use linked list for bubblesort academia unless you're specifically *not* supposed to swap direct values, but instead swap positions in the list of the containing nodes (a task that is considerably different than that done here).

Answer (score 1):

Do not increment `i`.  Since `j` starts from 1, so `i` should always begin loop from 0.
Change    `for(i=0; i<k-1; i++,k--)`
to    `for(i=0; i<k-1; k--)`

`for(i=0; i<k-1; i++,k--)` should run k-1 times. But when you are incrementing `i` and decrementing `k`, then difference between `i` and `k` decreases at twice the rate, so it runs `k/2` times and so  only `k/2` elements are sorting. And when run again, remaining `k/2` elements are also sorted.

Comment: You are right, I tried minimum editing to keep close to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following 2 lines

```
for(i=0; i<k-1; i++,k--) {

for(j = 1; j<k; j++) {
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < (k - 1); i++) {

for(j = 0; j < (k - i - 1); j++) {
```

Comment: Wow it works! But can u tell me how you thought about this looping condition?

Comment: I will leave it to you :), use a debugger and step through every iteration and check the values of each variable at every step, you will figure it out. If you don't I will explain.